# Gtk Terminal Widget

Tags: haskell, gtk, terminal, widget, gtk2hs

Simple question: Is there a linux-style terminal widget for GTK? Preferably for Haskell, too, as I want to use gtk2hs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[vte](http://developer.gnome.org/vte/unstable/) is what is used in gnome-terminal. It seems there are [vte haskell bindings](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vte).

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much the best and only candidate is [VTE](http://developer.gnome.org/vte/unstable/index.html). Not sure if you would need an explicit Haskell wrapper for the native library or not.